# Hibernate interface polymorphism mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am learning Hibernate recently, the basic concepts are clear for me, but I have a design problem now. All my concrete classes implement interfaces, here is the code:
    package com;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

public interface Person {
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getName();
    public void setId(Integer id);
    public Integer getId();
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon);
    public Weapon getWeapon();
}
```

````

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

public interface Weapon {
    public void setSharpness(Integer sharpness);
    public Integer getSharpness();
    public void setId(Integer id);
    public Integer getId();
}
```

````

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_inf")
public class PersonImpl implements Person{
    @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "person_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Weapon.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "weapon_id",referencedColumnName = "weapon_id")
    private Weapon weapon;
setters and getters omitted
}
```

````
    package com;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "weapon_inf")
public class WeaponImpl implements Weapon {
    @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "weapon_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "weapon_sharpness")
    private Integer sharpness;
    setters and getters omitted
}
```

When I try the hibernate program (save a person's instance), it throws

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.PersonImpl.weapon references an unknown entity: com.Weapon
```

Is there a solution or annotation to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference `WeaponImpl` instead of `Weapon` as your entity class is `WeaponImpl`.

That gives you field

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "weapon_id",referencedColumnName = "weapon_id")
private WeaponImpl weapon;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `WeaponImpl`  instead of `Weapon` like this:

```
  @OneToOne(targetEntity = WeaponImpl.class)
```